# Indy 9 to Indy 10 conversion

Tags: delphi, pascal, indy10

I have found an old `.dpr` file on the internet, the file is basically a Delphi 7 project from 2008 about server-emulation of an old game.

I tried to compile the file using RAD Studio, but it seemed that the file was using Indy 9 units/libs, where the availabe Indy that comes with RAD Studio is Indy 10.

The codes I want to convert are the ones with errors.

```
procedure aServer.Map_ServerExecute(AThread: TIdContext);
var
  i, n: integer;
  sz: integer;
  incom_buf: array[0..8192] of byte;
  str: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to max_connects do
    if Assigned(map_connections[i]) then
      if map_connections[i] = AThread then break;
  n := i;
  if i >= max_connects then exit;
  for i := 0 to 8191 do
    incom_buf[i] := 0;
  sz := AThread.Connection.ReadFromStack(); // E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ReadFromStack'
  AThread.Connection.ReadBuffer(incom_buf,sz); // E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ReadBuffer'
  decrypt_pkt(incom_buf, sz);
  if do_debug_output <> 0 then
  begin
    str := ByteArrayToHexString(incom_buf, sz-1);
    Writeln('in>'+str);
  end;
  sv_callback(n, 1, sz, @incom_buf[0]);
end;
```

```
procedure write_to_n(n: integer; is_map: integer; sz: integer; p:pointer); stdcall;
var
  TheThread: TIdContext; 
  i: integer;
  out_buf: array [0..2048] of byte;
  p_out_buf: PByteArray;
  str: string;
begin
  if n < 0 then exit;
  if n > max_connects then exit; 
  if sz <= 0 then exit;
  TheThread := nil;
  if is_map = 0 then
    TheThread := chr_connections[n]
  else 
    TheThread := map_connections[n];
  if not Assigned(TheThread) then exit;
  for i := 0 to 2048 do
    out_buf[i] := 0;
  p_out_buf := p;
  for i := 0 to sz do
    out_buf[i] := p_out_buf[i];
  if do_debug_output <> 0 then
  begin
    str := ByteArrayToHexString(out_buf, sz-1);
    Writeln('out>'+str);
  end;
  decrypt_pkt(out_buf, sz);
  TheThread.Connection.WriteBuffer(out_buf,sz-1); // E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'WriteBuffer' 
end;
```

I tried a few conversions from the internet, but other errors kept arising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Indy 10, most of the reading/writing methods were moved from `TIdTCPConnection` to `TIdIOHandler`, and also redesigned.  For instance, Indy 10 supports .NET, so raw pointers to memory buffers are no longer accepted (that may change in a future version), so you have to use either the `TIdBytes` (dynamic array of bytes) type, or a `TId(ReadOnly)MemoryBufferStream` instead.

So, in the code you have shown, try the following changes...

Using `TIdBytes`:

```
procedure aServer.Map_ServerExecute(AThread: TIdContext);
var
  i, n: integer;
  sz: integer;
  incom_buf: TIdBytes;
  str: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to max_connects do
    if Assigned(map_connections[i]) then
      if map_connections[i] = AThread then break;
  n := i;
  if i >= max_connects then exit;
  AThread.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource;
  sz := AThread.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size;
  if sz = 0 then exit;
  AThread.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(incom_buf, sz);
  decrypt_pkt(PByte(incom_buf), sz);
  if do_debug_output <> 0 then
  begin
    str := ByteArrayToHexString(PByte(incom_buf), sz-1); // why -1?
    Writeln('in>'+str);
  end;
  sv_callback(n, 1, sz, PByte(incom_buf));
end;
```

```
procedure write_to_n(n: integer; is_map: integer; sz: integer; p: Pointer); stdcall;
var
  TheThread: TIdContext; 
  i: integer;
  out_buf: TIdBytes;
  str: string;
begin
  if n < 0 then exit;
  if n > max_connects then exit; 
  if sz <= 0 then exit;
  TheThread := nil;
  if is_map = 0 then
    TheThread := chr_connections[n]
  else 
    TheThread := map_connections[n];
  if not Assigned(TheThread) then exit;
  out_buf := RawToBytes(p^, sz);
  if do_debug_output <> 0 then
  begin
    str := ByteArrayToHexString(PByte(out_buf), sz-1); // why -1?
    Writeln('out>'+str);
  end;
  decrypt_pkt(PByte(out_buf), sz);
  TheThread.Connection.IOHandler.Write(out_buf, sz-1); // why -1?
end;
```

Alternatively, using `TId(ReadOnly)MemoryBufferStream`:

```
procedure aServer.Map_ServerExecute(AThread: TIdContext);
var
  i, n: integer;
  sz: integer;
  incom_buf: array[0..8192] of byte;
  incom_strm: TIdMemoryBufferStream;
  str: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to max_connects do
    if Assigned(map_connections[i]) then
      if map_connections[i] = AThread then break;
  n := i;
  if i >= max_connects then exit;
  ZeroMemory(incom_buf, SizeOf(incom_buf));
  AThread.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource;
  sz := AThread.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size;
  if sz = 0 then exit;
  incom_strm := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(incom_buf, SizeOf(incom_buf));
  try
    AThread.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(incom_strm, sz);
  finally
    incom_strm.Free;
  end;
  decrypt_pkt(incom_buf, sz);
  if do_debug_output <> 0 then
  begin
    str := ByteArrayToHexString(incom_buf, sz-1); // why -1?
    Writeln('in>'+str);
  end;
  sv_callback(n, 1, sz, @incom_buf[0]);
end;
```

```
procedure write_to_n(n: integer; is_map: integer; sz: integer; p: Pointer); stdcall;
var
  TheThread: TIdContext; 
  i: integer;
  out_buf: array [0..2048] of byte;
  p_out_buf: PByteArray;
  out_strm: TIdReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream;
  str: string;
begin
  if n < 0 then exit;
  if n > max_connects then exit; 
  if sz <= 0 then exit;
  TheThread := nil;
  if is_map = 0 then
    TheThread := chr_connections[n]
  else 
    TheThread := map_connections[n];
  if not Assigned(TheThread) then exit;
  ZeroMemory(out_buf, SizeOf(out_buf));
  CopyMemory(out_buf, p, sz);
  if do_debug_output <> 0 then
  begin
    str := ByteArrayToHexString(out_buf, sz-1); // why -1?
    Writeln('out>'+str);
  end;
  decrypt_pkt(out_buf, sz);
  // NOTE: passing ASize=0 to IOHandler.Write(TStream) will send the entire stream instead of sending nothing...
  if sz = 1 then exit;
  out_strm := TIdReadOnlyMemoryBufferStream.Create(out_buf, SizeOf(out_buf));
  try
    TheThread.Connection.IOHandler.Write(out_strm, sz-1); // why -1?
  finally
    out_strm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you really want 2049 and 8193 byte buffers, or is that a typo ?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Maybe Data + ``\0`` ;-)

Comment: The server is running, the game client connects, I can move the player around after a while the server stops recieving packets from the client!

Comment: @MeskanovaGin then you will just have to debug the comms and find out what is really happening. The code I gave you is a 1:1 translation from Indy 9 to 10, the logic *should* act the same as before

Comment: @RemyLebeau no need, ur alternative mthod is working great! thanks again.